# Como passar esse parâmetro para um função void?

Tags: c

Tendo duas funções sendo a primeira :

```
void print_bytes (const void * end_byte, int n){
    int k;
    k = end_byte;
    converte_binario(k);
}
```

Já a converte binária é um pouco grande então irei explicar, basicamente ela converte um numero inteiro para binário.
Não estou conseguindo compilar o código, pois não sei passar o K como parâmetro para a função converte_binario.
Já tentei:

```
k = *end_byte;
k = (int)end_byte;
k = (int*)end_byte;
```

E todas dão erro, gostaria de saber como passar o K ou ate mesmo o end_byte como parâmetro para a função converte_binario.

PS : Aqui vai o "protótipo" da função converte_binario.

```
void converte_binario (int n);
```

Comment: Voce deve usar assim: k =  * ((int * ) end_byte);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua função `print_bytes` recebe um ponteiro em `end_byte`. Para que você consiga atribuir para `k` o valor inteiro para o qual aquele ponteiro aponta você deve fazer:

```
k = * (int*)end_byte;
```

Esta sintaxe está dizendo ao compilador que você está tentando desreferenciar um ponteiro que aponta para um número inteiro (o tipo de `k`). Como `end_byte` é um ponteiro para `void`, você deve, antes, fazer a conversão para um ponteiro para inteiro, para que o compilador saiba quantos bytes utilizar na hora de desreferenciá-lo: `(int*)end_byte`.

Então você poderá chamar a função `converte_binario` com:

```
converte_binario(k);
```

Dessa forma, o valor binário não pode ser armazenado em `k`. Isso quer dizer: você não terá acesso ao valor convertido, de dentro da função `print_bytes`.

Se a função `print_bytes` não precisar conhecer o binário convertido, isso não é problema. Caso contrário, você deve implementar uma forma de que esse valor seja retornado (seja passando um ponteiro como argumento e escrevendo o binário nesse ponteiro ou retornando algo da função `converte_binario`).

Comment: Mesmo colocando k = (int) *end_byte o compilador acusa os seguintes erros : "Invalid use of void expression" e "dereferencing 'void * ' pointer"

Comment: Falha minha: o correto seria `k = * (int*)end_byte;`. Vou corrigir a resposta e explicar o motivo.

Comment: Agora resolveu o problema, vlw